# MongoDb c# driver enum mapping

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have Enum:

```
public enum SomeType
{
   TypeA,
   TypeB, 
   TypeC
}
```

but in MongoDB i would like this map to:
type_a type_b type_c

I'm using EnumRepresentationConvention(BsonType.String)

I tried:

```
public enum SomeType
{
   [BsonElement("type_a")]
   TypeA,
   [BsonElement("type_b")]
   TypeB, 
   [BsonElement("type_c")]
   TypeC
}
```

but this doesn't work. Im getting exception:

Requested value 'type_a' was not found.

Is anyone know how can achieve such mapping in MongoDb C# driver?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

So I wrote a new serializer that does what you need. I built it off some code I wrote as part of [SharpExtensions](https://github.com/thegreatco/SharpExtensions/blob/master/src/SharpExtensions/Enum%20Extensions/EnumExtensions.cs). It certainly isn't optimized (or as simplified as it could be) but it works.

First I created a sample class `Foo` and reused your example `Enum`. I then leveraged the [`DescriptionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) to specify an alternate representation of the `Enum` that you completely control. Though this could be potentially simplified if you leverage something like `Humanizer` to consistently change the representation.

I then created a `BsonSerializationProvider` to let the driver know when it should use that serializer (much like my original answer). The meat is in `EnumDescriptionSerializer` which uses reflection to find the string representation of a particular value of `SomeType`. This is where I leverage the boilerplate code from `SharpExtensions` to move between the string and the actual `Enum` value. You'll notice the code will also work with `EnumMemberAttribute` as well as `DescriptionAttribute`. Please feel free to import the `SharpExtensions` library if you don't want to use the boilerplate code directly.

```
public class Foo
{
    public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
    public SomeType Enum {get;set;}
}

public enum SomeType
{
    [Description("type_a")]
    TypeA,
    [Description("type_b")]
    TypeB,
    [Description("type_c")]
    TypeC
}

public class EnumDescriptionSerializerProvider : BsonSerializationProviderBase
{
    public override IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type, IBsonSerializerRegistry registry)
    {
        if (!type.GetTypeInfo().IsEnum) return null;

        var enumSerializerType = typeof(EnumDescriptionSerializer<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        var enumSerializerConstructor = enumSerializerType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
        var enumSerializer = (IBsonSerializer)enumSerializerConstructor?.Invoke(new object[0]);

        return enumSerializer;
    }
}

public class EnumDescriptionSerializer<TEnum> : StructSerializerBase<TEnum> where TEnum : struct
{
    public BsonType Representation => BsonType.String;

    public override TEnum Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var valAsString = context.Reader.ReadString();
        var enumValue = valAsString.GetValueFromDescription<TEnum>();
        return enumValue;
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TEnum value)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteString(value.GetDescription());
    }
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{

    public enum StringCase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The default capitalization
        /// </summary>
        Default,
        /// <summary>
        /// Lower Case, ex. i like widgets.
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Lower Case")]
        Lower,
        /// <summary>
        /// Upper Case, ex. I LIKE WIDGETS.
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Upper Case")]
        Upper,
        /// <summary>
        /// Lower Camelcase, ex: iLikeWidgets.
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Lower Camelcase")]
        LowerCamel,
        /// <summary>
        /// Upper Camelcase, ex: ILikeWidgets.
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Upper Camelcase")]
        UpperCamel
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the value of an enum as a string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="val"> The enum to convert to a <see cref="string"/>. </param>
    /// <param name="case"> A <see cref="StringCase"/> indicating which case to return.  Valid enumerations are StringCase.Lower and StringCase.Upper. </param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"> If the enum is null. </exception>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetName<TEnum>(this TEnum val, StringCase @case = StringCase.Default) where TEnum : struct
    {
        var name = Enum.GetName(val.GetType(), val);
        if (name == null) return null;

        switch (@case)
        {
            case StringCase.Lower:
                return name.ToLower();
            case StringCase.Upper:
                return name.ToUpper();
            default:
                return name;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the description for the supplied Enum Value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="val">The value for which to get the description attribute.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="string"/> description.</returns>
    public static string GetDescription<TEnum>(this TEnum val) where TEnum : struct
    {
        var fields = val.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredField(GetName(val));

        // first try and pull out the EnumMemberAttribute, common when using a JsonSerializer
        if (fields.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() is EnumMemberAttribute jsonAttribute) return jsonAttribute.Value;

        // If that doesn't work, do the regular description, that still fails, just return a pretty ToString().
        return !(fields.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() is DescriptionAttribute attribute) ? GetName(val) : attribute.Description;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the value of an <see cref="Enum"/> based on its description attribute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the <see cref="Enum"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="description">The Description attribute of the <see cref="Enum"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>The value of T or default(T) if the description is not found.</returns>
    public static T GetValueFromDescription<T>(this string description) where T : struct
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(description));

        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.GetTypeInfo().IsEnum) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(T), $"{typeof(T)} is not an Enum.");
        var fields = type.GetRuntimeFields();

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            if (field.Name == description) return (T)field.GetValue(null);

            // first try and pull out the EnumMemberAttribute, common when using a JsonSerializer
            if (field.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false) is EnumMemberAttribute jsonAttribute && jsonAttribute.Value == description) return (T)field.GetValue(null);

            // If that doesn't work, do the regular description, that still fails, just return a pretty ToString().
            if (field.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false) is DescriptionAttribute attribute && attribute.Description == description) return (T)field.GetValue(null);
        }

        throw new Exception($"Failed to parse value {description} into enum {typeof(T)}");
    }
}
```

I wrote a simple test inserti
ng several `Foo` documents into a collection. This is how they look in the database

```
> db.enum.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c76c0240bba918778cc6b7f"), "Enum" : "type_a" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c76c0580bba918778cc6b80"), "Enum" : "type_a" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c76c05d0bba918778cc6b81"), "Enum" : "type_b" }
```

I also verified that they round-trip correctly. I haven't run any tests beyond some simple code using LINQPad. I believe this is what you are looking for.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I wrote a custom serializer for this so I could register it and things "just work".

```
public class EnumAsStringSerializationProvider : BsonSerializationProviderBase
{
    public override IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type, IBsonSerializerRegistry registry)
    {
        if (!type.GetTypeInfo().IsEnum) return null;

        var enumSerializerType = typeof(EnumSerializer<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        var enumSerializerConstructor = enumSerializerType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(BsonType) });
        var enumSerializer = (IBsonSerializer) enumSerializerConstructor?.Invoke(new object[] { BsonType.String });

        return enumSerializer;
    }
}
```

Then I register it with the `BsonSerializer`.

```
var enumAsStringSerializationProvider = new EnumAsStringSerializationProvider();
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(enumAsStringSerializationProvider);
```

For me, it just works and I don't need to remember to decorate enums.

Comment: Ok, but you only registering serializer for enum - but how to tell serializer to map value string type_a to TypeA value of enum?

Comment: @JakubDropia I have updated my answer with what I believe you are looking for. Hope it helps.